# Помогите осознать механику кода

Tags: c, указатели

Изучаю СИ на сайте метанит и вот наткнулся на вот этот код:

```
#include <stdio.h>
 
int main(void)
{   
    char *fruit[] = {"apricot", "apple", "banana", "lemon", "pear", "plum"};
    int n = sizeof(fruit)/sizeof(fruit[0]);
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        printf("%s \n", fruit[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Решил разобрать код, и для начала вывел на экран sizeof(fruit) и sizeof(fruit[0]) и меня удивили значения 24 и 4 соответственно, был бы благодарен за пояснение этой ситуации.Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
char *fruit[] = {"apricot", "apple", "banana", "lemon", "pear", "plum"};
```

Из инициализации видно, что в массиве 6 элементов, шесть указателей `char*`. Ergo, `sizeof(fruit)` равен `6*sizeof(char*) = 6*4 = 24` (в 32-разрядном приложении).

Размер `sizeof(fruit[0])` равен размеру *одного* элемента, одного `char*` - `sizeof(char*) == 4` байта.

Вот и все чудеса...

Comment: а почему именно 4?

Comment: Потому что 32-разрядное приложение. 32 = 4*8 - 4 байта. Стандартный размер указателя. В 64-разрядном указатель уже 8 байт.

Comment: Этого я не знал,теперь всё понял, спасибо